# How to order obj based on their hierachy?

Tags: c#, linq

Given 2 object `People` and `Relation`:

```
public class People
{   
    public int id ;
    public string externalId;
    public PostalInfo postalInformation;
}

public class Relation
{        
    public int id ;
    public int type ;
    public string sourceExternalId ;
    public string destExternalId ;
}
```

Where `People` store the information about someone.
And `Relation` store the connexion between 2 `People`.

#### How to order people based on their hierachy, from the "oldest" (the one deeper) to the less important one?

By older, I mean the element that have less bound to other. So when ordered I can validate and create those element without missing reference. But as validation is made by an human, I can't wait all of them to be validate to submit them all once.

```
var peoplesAwaitingValidation =
    new List<People> {
        new People{ id = 1 , externalId = "A" },
        new People{ id = 2 , externalId = "B" },
        new People{ id = 3 , externalId = "C" },
        new People{ id = 4 , externalId = "D" },
        new People{ id = 5 , externalId = "E" },
        new People{ id = 6 , externalId = "F" },
    };

var relationsAwaitingValidation =
    new List<Relation> {
        new Relation{ id = 1 , sourceExternalId = "A", destExternalId = "B" },
        new Relation{ id = 2 , sourceExternalId = "A", destExternalId = "C" },
        new Relation{ id = 3 , sourceExternalId = "A", destExternalId = "D" },
        new Relation{ id = 4 , sourceExternalId = "E", destExternalId = "A" },
        new Relation{ id = 3 , sourceExternalId = "E", destExternalId = "B" }
    };

//Expected result :
var orderedPeoplesAwaitingValidation = new List<People> {
                                                    // Weight
        new People{ id = 6 , externalId = "F" },    // 0 
        new People{ id = 5 , externalId = "E" },    // 1
        new People{ id = 1 , externalId = "A" },    // 2 
        new People{ id = 3 , externalId = "C" },    // 3
        new People{ id = 4 , externalId = "D" },    // 3
        new People{ id = 2 , externalId = "B" },    // 5
    };
```

Graphical representation I have in mind:

> ```
> 1        2        3   // <==  Weight
> E  --->  A  --->  B
>             --->  C
>             --->  D
>    --->  B
>
> F==0
> ```

[mcve and attempt](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7TAfN)

Comment: I'm not seeing a clear definition of 'older' or 'weight'. Can you be specific?

Comment: And what if "B" has a relation to "E" ?  Any rules about/against cycles?

Comment: so the weight is accumulative? B has `5` because `E  --->  A  --->  B = 3` plus `E   --->  B = 2` ?

Comment: Sorry for beeing late, @HenkHolterman, no! No circle reference they are filter before.

Comment: @MongZhu, yes and no. Yes in this mental representation of a solution weight are cumulative but the max weight seems to be a better solution. It's only a simple vision i have facing this issue. as So require a mcve I added it. but it can be miss leading to someone having an other / better way of doing it. The aim is to have an orderer list so on creation we don't have a missing reference.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I will try to edit more specific information in the question. I hope it's not more confusing.

Comment: An mcve is great but we would like it here, inside the question. External links go dead.

Comment: "The aim is to have an orderer list so on creation ..."  is the ordered list an end product or a means to an end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate multiple times over your relations to find new relations that start at a point of wich we know the weight.

```
Dictionary<string, int> weights = peoplesAwaitingValidation
    .Where(x => relationsAwaitingValidation
        .Count(o => o.destExternalId == x.externalId) == 0)
    .ToDictionary(o => o.externalId, o => 0);
int processed = 0;
while (processed < relationsAwaitingValidation.Count - 1)
    foreach (Relation r in relationsAwaitingValidation)
        if (weights.ContainsKey(r.sourceExternalId) &&
           !weights.ContainsKey(r.destExternalId))
        {
            weights.Add(r.destExternalId, weights[r.sourceExternalId] + 1);
            processed++;
        }
```

**Note:** This code assumes that there is always atleast one root person that has no connections to it.

Comment: This counting starts at 0, to start at 1 simply change the 0 in the .ToDictionary call

Comment: Well it's working! Thx. I generaly wait few days befor validating an answer. May I format the first line of code into multiple line so it's a little bit more readable with no horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Unsure, but maybe `.Where(...).Count()` could be rewritten `.Count(...)` (the same way you can use `.First(...)` instead of `.Where(...).First()`) - see [msdn Queryable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ofcourse :), I do not know if this is the fastest way, perhaps you could look into making the relations 'extendable'/'stackable' so you can say E => A => B (for example). This may increase your datasize a bit but saves you an brute-force operation like this. But this is only needed if you are dealing with large sets

Comment: @Rafalon, this is true, I updated the answer. @ Drag and Drop, can you mark this as the answer so others can find it too?

Comment: @H.J.Meijer he wrote "*I generaly wait few days befor validating an answer*", so he will, don't worry :) (unless a better solution shows up I guess)

Comment: See didn't forget you. I alway review all my action comment, vote, answer question at the end of the week. If they are old enought ^^